Discord Auto Delete
I am trying to make a Discord auto-delete script with SendInput but there is a problem when I run the script twice: the first time it's all good, then the second time it doesn't respond properly.
This function is called on the delete of message: it's supposed to be up, ctrl-a, backspace, enter, enter.
static bool DelDiscordMsg()
{
    INPUT inputs[9] = {};
    ZeroMemory(inputs, sizeof(inputs));

    inputs[0].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    inputs[0].ki.wVk = VK_UP;
    inputs[1].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    inputs[1].ki.wVk = VK_UP;
    inputs[1].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
    inputs[2].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    inputs[2].ki.wVk = VK_CONTROL;
    inputs[3].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    inputs[3].ki.wVk = 'A';
    inputs[4].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    inputs[4].ki.wVk = VK_CONTROL;
    inputs[4].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
    inputs[5].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    inputs[5].ki.wVk = VK_BACK;
    inputs[6].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    inputs[6].ki.wVk = VK_RETURN;
    inputs[7].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    inputs[7].ki.wVk = VK_RETURN;
    inputs[8].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    inputs[8].ki.wVk = VK_RETURN;
    

    UINT uSent = SendInput(ARRAYSIZE(inputs), inputs, sizeof(INPUT));
    if (uSent != ARRAYSIZE(inputs))
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

static bool NextMsg()
{
    INPUT inputs[4] = {};
    ZeroMemory(inputs, sizeof(inputs));
    Sleep(300);
    inputs[0].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    inputs[0].ki.wVk = VK_RETURN;
    inputs[1].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    inputs[1].ki.wVk = VK_BACK;
    Sleep(300);
    inputs[2].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    inputs[2].ki.wVk = VK_UP;
    Sleep(300);
    inputs[3].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    inputs[3].ki.wVk = VK_UP;
    inputs[3].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
    UINT uSent = SendInput(ARRAYSIZE(inputs), inputs, sizeof(INPUT));
    if (uSent != ARRAYSIZE(inputs))
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

This function is to get to the message every time it does DelDiscordMsg.
Main:
int main()
{
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(3));
    bool flag = true;
    NextMsg();
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        Sleep(500);
        flag=DelDiscordMsg();
        if (flag==false)
        {
            break;
        }
        Sleep(500);
        NextMsg();
    }
}


In your second snippet you have Sleep calls between the field assignments. That's not going to add a delay between the input events because SendInput will send them at once. Instead, make multiple calls to SendInput with delays in between.

Is there a reason you are not using Discord API and instead try to simulate keyboard input from user?

Yes Yksisarvinen, I am pretty lazy and thought it will be easier doing it like this
